# float banner ad at the bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-activity, admob, banner-ads

I have following xml design -

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/wall"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ahl.XXXXX.MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/XXXXX"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@color/XXXXX"
            android:onClick="openXXXXX"
            android:text="@string/XXXXX" 
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/XXXXX"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:background="@color/XXXXX"
            android:onClick="openXXXXX"
            android:text="@string/XXXXX" 
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/XXXXX"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@color/XXXXX"
            android:onClick="openXXXXX"
            android:text="@string/XXXXX"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/XXXXX"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/Gray"
            android:onClick="openXXXXX"
            android:text="@string/XXXXX"
            android:textColor="@color/White"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewB1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6805003743867442/4243673212" >

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/WebView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to float banner ad at the bottom of screen. I tried using relative layout but It is not working well with webview. I have seen other questions like this but here webview is causing some problems as it covers all the screen ... so I had to use linearlayout.

Do I have to float ad over webview OR over parent Linearlayout??

What changes I can do in the above XML to get the ad at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: why does your webview cover the whole screen when you use relative layout? You can set its height.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you mean is that you want the AdView to be displayed at the bottom of the screen. You really don't want to *float* the AdView over anything.

Set your WebView to expand to fill unused space using `layout_weight="1"` and have the AdView displayed below that. Eg.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</ScrollView>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adViewB1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-6805003743867442/4243673212" >

</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```